# Can I get edge headless to run a js file through command line?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I might be barking up the wrong tree, but, is there a way to get edge browser to execute some js files from a console please?
Assume I have a js file with some simple lines thrown in, something like:

```
// index.js
console.log('Hello world!');

activate('quick brown fox');

function activate(msg) {
  console.log(`message: ${msg}`);
}
```

Now, I've got edge installed and can invoke it with the command `MicrosoftEdge.exe`. I've looked at the [chromium command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but cannot figure out how to get edge to run my `index.js` (or `index.html or whatever I may have)

Is that possible to do please? When I do `MicrosftEdge.exe --headless` the command finishes without waiting (or opening a repl or waiting) so I'm not sure what to do here

Answer (score 3):

Visiting the URL of a JS file will just show the contents of the file, so it'll be a boring debugging session.

Let's make a html file that uses it as you suggested and use remote debugging in MS Edge.

### HTML file

```html
<html>
  <head><title>JS test</title></head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Command line

Use the path of where your executable is, important part is the `--remote-debugging-port` parameter, which will halt the executable and wait for a debugging session.

```bash
msedge.exe --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 file:///C:/Users/example/htdocs/index.html

DevTools listening on ws://[::1]:9222/devtools/browser/feedbeef-beef-f00d-f00d-feedbeefbaadf00d
```

### Activate remote debugging in MS edge

Check if remote debugging is enabled in MS Edge.
Visit `edge://flags` and search for *remote* and explicitly set it to enabled if the next step isn't working.

[image: Activate remote debugging in the experiments flags]

Older versions of Edge may require a download of this as a beta feature.

Further details: [Edge remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/windows)

### Connect to your remote debugging session

Visit `edge://inspect/` and enter `http://localhost:9222` in the location field. Clicking "Connect to Device" may take a bit, but after a while it will open the remote debugging session.

[image: enter the remote debugging URL]

Switching to the console tab here will now show the console output from your script or whatever you want to debug.

[image: debug console output]